# Undefined method 'destroy' when attempting to destroy/decline friendship relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, relationship

I've set up a self-referencing relationship model for users to be friends with one another. I am able to create a friend request (two entries in my DB, one for the friendship and one for the inverse friendship) without any problems.

I am having trouble declining a friend request though. I keep getting this error when I press decline which takes me to the destroy action:

```
NoMethodError in FriendshipsController#destroy
undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass
```

One of the database records, pending friendship, is destroyed even though I get the error above, and if I comment out `@friendship2 = @user.friendships.find_by_friend_id(params[:id]).destroy`, the other record gets destroyed too. So it looks like both line are work individually, but returns the above error.

SOLUTION: It looks like my two destroy statements were referencing the same record. I've commented out the wrong code in my controller and added the ones that work for me.

Here is my Friendships controller:

```
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:update, :create, :destroy]

def create
  @user = User.find(current_user)
  @friend = User.find(params[:friend_id])
  params[:friendship1] = {:user_id => @user.id, :friend_id => @friend.id, :status => 'requested'}
  params[:friendship2] = {:user_id => @friend.id, :friend_id => @user.id, :status => 'pending'}
  @friendship1 = Friendship.create(params[:friendship1])
  @friendship2 = Friendship.create(params[:friendship2])
  redirect_to @friend
 end  
end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @friend = User.find(params[:id])
    #@friendship2 = @user.friendships.find_by_friend_id(params[:id]).destroy
    #@friendship1 = @friend.friendships.find_by_id(params[:user_id]).destroy  
    @friendship1 = @user.friendships.find_by_friend_id(@friend.id).destroy #removes the requested friendship
    @friendship2 = @friend.friendships.find_by_friend_id(@user.id).destroy #removes the pending friendship

    flash[:success] = "Removed."
    redirect_to @user   
  end 
end
```

Here is my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friendships, :dependent => :destroy

  has_many :friends, 
     :through => :friendships, 
     :conditions => "status = 'accepted'", 
     :source => :friend 

  has_many :pending_friends, 
     :through => :friendships, 
     :conditions => "status = 'pending'", 
     :foreign_key => "user_id", 
     :source => :friend

  has_many :requested_friends, 
     :through => :friendships,
     :source => :friend, 
     :conditions => "status = 'requested'"    
end
```

Here is my view (users/show.html.erb):

```
<% if signed_in? && @user == current_user %>
  <% unless current_user.pending_friends.empty? %>
    <h2>Pending</h2>
    <% current_user.pending_friends.each do |pending| %>
       <%= pending.name %>
       <%= link_to '[Accept]', friendship_path(:user_id => current_user, :id => pending), :method => :put, :confirm => "Accept?" %>
       <%= link_to '[Decline]', friendship_path(:user_id => current_user, :id => pending), :method => :delete, :confirm => "Decline?" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I have two questions.

1. I've seen from some tutorials/discussion about [the use of inverse_friendships](http://iterat.ive.ly/index.php/2010/08/31/a-user-friend-relationship-model-in-rails/), but is this really necessary? So far, I haven't seen the need for this, but then again, I've only gotten as far as coding my create and destroy action.
2. What's up with the undefined method 'destroy' error?

Thanks for getting through this wall of text! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the first one, it's up to you and your system. Creating different variable to hold every type of friendship might be a bit hardcore though, but it gives you full information, more control and there's no data duplication in the database.

Regarding the second one you should check whether your query return a result. Since your exception:

> undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass

Says there's no method "destroy" in NilClass (not friendship). Just check the :id parameter and whether find_by_friend_id returns anything at all.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying both questions. I am still having trouble locating the error and have included my view as well. I think the problem is in the line `@friendship1 = @friend.friendships.find_by_id(params[:user_id]).destroy`. Pardon my inexperience (still new to Rails). I'll continue looking into this.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This ultimately lead me to discovering the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Put check before destory .

```
friendship = @friend.friendships.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
@friendship1 = friendship.destroy if !friendship.nil?
```

And also use can make this destory into the model with the help of [callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) .

Comment: This helped me get closer to the solution. While this removed the error message, it still is not removing the requested_friendship. I was able to figure out that my two destroy is referencing the same record. Now I just have to figure out how to pass the friend_id as user_id...

Comment: Thank you for your help, Vik. I was able to figure it out. Gave Dmitriy the checkmark but upvoted you too.